# HibernateException: Missing sequence or table and SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, database-sequence

I am fairly new to hibernate and this is very strange  -  I am trying to run a Spring-Hibernate rest application on tomcat using eclipse. 
I have an entity defined as below -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bdp_billing_rec_ref")
@NamedQueries(value = { @NamedQuery(name = BillingRecordReference.BILLING_RECORD_REF_DELETE_OLDER_THAN, query = "DELETE FROM BillingRecordReference WHERE updated<:date") })
public class BillingRecordReference {
  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "bdp_billing_rec_ref_id_seq_gen", sequenceName = "bdp_billing_rec_ref_id_seq")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "bdp_billing_rec_ref_id_seq_gen")
  @Column(name = "db_id")
  private Long dbId;
```

Oracle maven dependency version is as below -

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
       <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
     </dependency>
```

With this, If I run the application , it throws exception as below -

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing sequence or table: bdp_billing_rec_ref_id_seq
```

The sequence **`bdp_billing_rec_ref_id_seq`** exists in database, I have made it sure.
After googling the issue, according to suggestions I modified the **GenerationType.AUTO**  to **GenerationType.IDENTITY** , and it worked . The Web Server started to run.

Now, the application tries to insert rows in to  **BillingRecordReference** table after hitting a rest endpoint. At this moment, hibernate throw another exception and values did not inserted in to table.

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DPOWNERA"."BDP_BILLING_REC_REF"."DB_ID")
```

The oracle version is 12c, I am running JAVA - openjdk version "1.8.0_181-1-ojdkbuild", Tomcat Version is 8.0.5.

Please suggest what could be wrong here ?

Comment: Did you tried change strategy to `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`? And add `unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false` to `@Column(...)`

Comment: `GenerationType.IDENTITY` requires the column to be a actual identity column to work. And as its the primary key, the value is not allowed to be null, which it is when inserting with identity column

Comment: @Dumbo yes sir, i did changed to Generation type.SEQUENCE , In this case , exception was - missing sequence

Comment: try native query annotation `@Query(value = "SELECT seq_name.nextval FROM dual", nativeQuery = true)`